# subsonic asp.net 3 layer architecture object model

Tags: asp.net, subsonic, object-model

i've been using subsonic for two years now (actually i'm using 2.1 version in my projects right now).

I'd like to structure a new project this way: presentation layer + business layer + data layer with an object model, vertical to the 3 layers, that models business entities. The matter is that subsonic, through the db reading, create entities with crud method inside.

Is it possible to split crud method between entities?
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - have a peak:
http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-writing-decoupled-testable-code-with-subsonic-2-1/